# How to create a simple association between two tables in Phoenix and submit the data

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am learning how to configure a belong_to / has_many relationship between two tables. I have the configuration complete but I don't know the syntax to invoke it. I want to take a pre-existing Table called Testbed and assign it to another Table called Group.

- Group has_many Testbeds
- Testbeds belong_to Group.

This is a document I am writing to record the process , so I walk through most of the steps to where I am now.

In Phoenix I generated the two tables and related UI code using these commands:

```
mix phx.gen.html Testbeds Testbed testbeds name:string

mix phx.gen.html Groups Group groups name:string
```

The command line prompted me to add the resources / route for both of them. I did what it said.

I ran:

```
mix ecto.migrate
```

**Testbed Migration**

For testbeds, I create a migration file and add this field:
**:group_id, references(:groups)**

```
defmodule App.Repo.Migrations.TestbedUpdate do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    alter table(:testbeds) do    
      add :group_id, references(:groups) # added
    end
  end
end
```

**Change Group Schema**

I update the Group schema. My changes are noted in Comments

```
defmodule App.Groups.Group do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  
  alias App.Testbeds.Testbed   # Alias!
  schema "groups" do
    field :name, :string
    has_many :testbeds, Testbed    # Has many
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(group, attrs) do
    group
    |> cast(attrs, [:name])
    |> validate_required([:name])
  end
end
```

**Change Testbed Schema**

```
defmodule App.Testbeds.Testbed do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias App.Groups.Group      # Alias
  schema "testbeds" do
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to :group, Group    # Belongs to
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(testbed, attrs) do
    testbed
    |> cast(attrs, [:name])
    |> validate_required([:name])
  end
end
```

I read that I needed to incorporate “preload” so that I can read data. So I did this:

```
  def list_testbeds do
    Repo.all(Testbed)
    |> Repo.preload([:group])
  end
```

and this

```
  def list_groups do
    Repo.all(Group)
     |> Repo.preload([:testbeds])
  end
```

When I create Groups and Testbeds and I query them, the result looks like this:

```
%App.Groups.Group{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "groups">,
    id: 3,
    name: "FUNK",
    testbeds: [],
    inserted_at: ~N[2023-09-27 18:13:15],
    updated_at: ~N[2023-09-27 18:13:15]
  }



%App.Testbeds.Testbed{
    __meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded, "testbeds">,
    id: 1,
    name: "Bloop",
    group_id: nil,
    group: nil,
    inserted_at: ~N[2023-09-27 14:04:15],
    updated_at: ~N[2023-09-27 18:22:23]
  }
```

I now need to know how to write code that assigns a Testbed to a Group.

**Create a Group**

```
App.Groups.create_group(%{name: "OINK"})
```

**Submit Testbed and Assign to a Group Association**

This code will create a new testbed and assign it to the Group that has an ID of 1.

```
group = App.Groups.get_group!(1)
thing = Ecto.build_assoc(group, :testbeds, name: "DUMB")
alias App.{Repo}
Repo.insert(thing)
```

When you query the group you will see one with a field name testbeds that is assigned a List. The List contains a Testbed struct.

So now my question, if I want to take a pre-created testbed and make the same kind of association that the previous commands did, what do I do? I simply don't know the syntax and everything that I've tried leads to error.

I've tried to create a testbed and assign it a group_id manually like this:

```
App.Testbeds.update_testbed(my_testbed,%{group_id: 2,name: "some-name"})
```

It doesn't affect the group_id and it remains nil.

**EDIT NOTE**

**These are the Testbed Function Created Per the Generator**

```
defmodule App.Testbeds do
  @moduledoc """
  The Testbeds context.
  """

  import Ecto.Query, warn: false
  alias App.Repo

  alias App.Testbeds.Testbed

  @doc """
  Returns the list of testbeds.

  ## Examples

      iex> list_testbeds()
      [%Testbed{}, ...]

  """
  def list_testbeds do
    Repo.all(Testbed)
    |> Repo.preload([:group])
  end

  @doc """
  Gets a single testbed.

  Raises `Ecto.NoResultsError` if the Testbed does not exist.

  ## Examples

      iex> get_testbed!(123)
      %Testbed{}

      iex> get_testbed!(456)
      ** (Ecto.NoResultsError)

  """
  def get_testbed!(id), do: Repo.get!(Testbed, id)

  @doc """
  Creates a testbed.

  ## Examples

      iex> create_testbed(%{field: value})
      {:ok, %Testbed{}}

      iex> create_testbed(%{field: bad_value})
      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{}}

  """
  def create_testbed(attrs \\ %{}) do
    %Testbed{}
    |> Testbed.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.insert()
  end

  @doc """
  Updates a testbed.

  ## Examples

      iex> update_testbed(testbed, %{field: new_value})
      {:ok, %Testbed{}}

      iex> update_testbed(testbed, %{field: bad_value})
      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{}}

  """
  def update_testbed(%Testbed{} = testbed, attrs) do
    testbed
    |> Testbed.changeset(attrs)
    |> Repo.update()
  end

  @doc """
  Deletes a testbed.

  ## Examples

      iex> delete_testbed(testbed)
      {:ok, %Testbed{}}

      iex> delete_testbed(testbed)
      {:error, %Ecto.Changeset{}}

  """
  def delete_testbed(%Testbed{} = testbed) do
    Repo.delete(testbed)
  end

  @doc """
  Returns an `%Ecto.Changeset{}` for tracking testbed changes.

  ## Examples

      iex> change_testbed(testbed)
      %Ecto.Changeset{data: %Testbed{}}

  """
  def change_testbed(%Testbed{} = testbed, attrs \\ %{}) do
    Testbed.changeset(testbed, attrs)
  end
end
```

Comment: That's because on your group changeset you're not casting anything related to the testbeds, so they just get ignored. You're probably looking for [cast_assoc/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3)

Comment: https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/associations.html will probably help too.

Comment: Can you share the implementation of `App.Testbeds.update_testbed` ?

Comment: I just did. It's at the bottom of the query and titled "EDIT NOTE These are the Testbed Function Created Per the Generator"

Comment: @sbacarob  I don't know how to use cast_assoc/3 or where I am supposed to put it. This is all boiler plate to me. I just wanted to create  a foreign key relationship and I am forced to do all this other stuff that I don't understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to update the schema to reference the group_id.

```
defmodule App.Testbeds.Testbed do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset
  alias App.Groups.Group      # Alias
  schema "testbeds" do
    field :name, :string
    belongs_to :group, Group    # Belongs to
    timestamps()
  end

  @doc false
  def changeset(testbed, attrs) do
    testbed
    |> cast(attrs, [:name, :group_id])   # group_id <--- Answer
    |> validate_required([:name])
  end
end
```

Then performing these commands adds the testbed to the group

```
group = App.Groups.get_group!(1)
item = App.Items.get_item!(1)
App.Items.update_item(item, %{group_id: group.id})
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax to manually create an association between a pre-existing Testbed and a Group is to

1. Retrieve the group you want to assign the testbed to using its ID:

   `group = App.Groups.get_group!(1)`
2. Retrieve the testbed you want to assign to the group using its ID:

   `testbed = App.Testbeds.get_testbed!(1)`
3. Build the association:

   `thing = Ecto.build_assoc(testbed, :group, group)`
4. Insert the association into the database using Repo.insert:

   `Repo.insert(thing)`

This will create the association between the testbed and the group, and the group_id field in the testbed will be updated with the ID of the group.

If you are receiving error when trying to insert a new Group, it means there must be a duplicate name in the database

adding an unique_constraint to the changeset options will solve this issue, as this will add the constraint as an error and prevent the duplicate value from being inserted into the database.

```
  def changeset(group, attrs) do
    group
    |> cast(attrs, [:name])
    |> validate_required([:name])
    |> unique_constraint(:name)
  end
```

or you can check for duplicate names before inserting or updating the record using Ecto's Repo module.

Comment: ** (Ecto.ConstraintError) constraint error when attempting to insert struct:

    * "groups_pkey" (unique_constraint)

If you would like to stop this constraint violation from raising an
exception and instead add it as an error to your changeset, please
call `unique_constraint/3` on your changeset with the constraint
`:name` as an option.

The changeset has not defined any constraint.

Comment: @William there must be a duplicate name in the database

Comment: @William updated the answer

Comment: There is no duplicate names. There are only a few items in the entire thing. I added your changeset code and there was no change

Comment: error message mentions calling the `unique_constraint/3` function on the changeset with the constraint :name as an option

add it and inspect and see what it shows:  `|> unique_constraint(:name)`

Comment: Yes, I did that. I have it placed their now. I recompiled and I get the same error

Comment: @William well hard to debug now

Comment: I started with a new mix ecto.create and recreated the tables. It still gives me the error

Comment: revert it and try with new group id and if it still doesnt work, then It would be helpful to see your full code

Comment: Most of it is just a generic Phoenix instance. As I said in the query, I generated mostly everything with the generators. The only exception are the migration files and the small schema change. All of that is documented in the query. I try with a completely new instance

Comment: 1. In your Testbed database, change the association "groups" to "group" so that it refers to a single group rather than multiple groups.

2. In your Ecto.build_assoc function, use the name of the association (group) instead of the name of the field (testbeds).

3. When you use Ecto.build_assoc, the "group_id" attribute will be automatically set for you, so there is no need to specify it when you insert the data into the database using Repo.insert.


`thing = Ecto.build_assoc(group, :group, name: "DUMB")`

didnt notice it earlier , could be potential cause

Comment: 1.  Are you referring to this line:   add :group_id, references(:groups). It's a bit difficult to understand. you might want to edit the answer outside of the comment section so you have more space for examples.